# How to get the current selected item from a Bootstrap filter/search?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create a filter/search feature in Bootstrap. Whenever the user is searching for an item and the filter narrows the selection done to one result then, if they choose enter or they "select" the item. It should populate the field with that item. I have the basic functionality down, however I can't seem to get the selecting the item part.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myList").toggle();

  $("#myInput").on("focus", function() {
    $("#myList").toggle();
  });

  $("#myInput").on("focusout", function() {
    $("#myList").toggle();
  });

  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {

    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myList li").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Filterable List</h2>
  <p>Type something in the input field to search the list for specific items:</p>
  <input class="form-control" id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
  <br>
  <ul class="list-group" id="myList">
    <li class="list-group-item">First item</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Second item</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Third item</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Fourth</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

My end goal is to be able to select an item and have it autocomplete it and populate the field.

Answer (score 0):

To populate the field, you can just put a `click` event in the items and, when one of them is clicked, get its text and set in the field.

The problem with this is that your `focusout` event triggers before the `click` event on the item, so it hides the list before the `click` event takes effect.

To overcome this, you can set a small timeout (I put 100 miliseconds) to hide the list after the `click` event. And everything will work!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myList").toggle();

  $("#myInput").on("focus", function() {
    $("#myList").toggle();
  });

  $("#myInput").on("focusout", function() {
    // Here, it'll wait 100 miliseconds to hide the list.
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("#myList").toggle();
    }, 100);
  });

  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

    $("#myList li").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });

  // This is the code to populate the field after selecting an option.
  $("#myList li").on("click", function() {
    var texto = $(this).text();
    $("#myInput").val(texto);
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Filterable List</h2>
  <p>Type something in the input field to search the list for specific items:</p>
  <input class="form-control" id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
  <br>
  <ul class="list-group" id="myList">
    <li class="list-group-item">First item</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Second item</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Third item</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Fourth</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work, I made a couple edits but still can't get the name into the input field.

Comment: @kane_004 but it's working in the snippet, right? What's not working for you?

Comment: When you click in an item of the list, the text is updated in the field. That's what it's doing in the snippet. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: Yes, it works now. Im so sorry, 100% just yesterday this code snippet did not work, but when I tried it just now, it works. Thanks again

Comment: No problem. If you think it was useful, you can accept the answer clicking in the check icon on the left.  :)